# How to break a part of a Conda command to a new line?

Tags: cmd, conda

My Conda command is too long, is there a way to break it to a new line?

```
conda create --name myenv python, package1, package2, package3, package4, package5, package6, etc
```

PS: yes, I know that I can use YAML file to install all of it but what about the Command Prompt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you already try using a backslash?

Something like:

```
conda create --name myenv python, package1, package2, package3, \
package4, package5, package6
```